# SharedPreferences recebendo NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Estou necessitando de uma ajuda no SharedPreference.
Estou desenvolvendo um APP de frases, onde existe um checkbox que marca as frases favoritas e joga essas frases no SharedPreferences onde poderão ser acessados a partir de um botão chamado favoritos.

O problema é que se clicarmos em favoritos sem ter nenhum favorito no qual é acionado quando se marca o checkbox, ele fecha o app e pelo log apresenta a seguinte mensagem:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Gostaria de contornar essa situação, até se possível já deixar um valor predefinido no sharedpreference se for o caso ou outra alternativa.

Segue o meu código, se puderem me ajudar...

```
// EVENTO DE CLIQUE

           lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {


                   // CHECK BOX

                   View checkBoxView = View.inflate(FraseAutorFrase.this, R.layout.checkbox, null);

                   CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                   checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                       @Override
                       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                           // Save to shared preferences

                           SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("arquivoPreferencia",MODE_PRIVATE);
                           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                           editor.putString("frase" + position, frasesR[position]);
                           editor.commit();


                       }
                   });
                   checkBox.setText("Marcar como Favorito?");
```

Essas informações são passadas para outra Activity

```
* ACTIVITY FAVORITOS

final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("arquivoPreferencia", MODE_PRIVATE);

        // CRIANDO A LISTA PARA RECEBER OS FAVORITOS

        final List<String> frasesFavoritoArray = new ArrayList<>();

        // TRANSFORMANDO ARRAY EM STRING

        Object[] objectList = frasesFavoritoArray.toArray();
        final String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(objectList, objectList.length, String[].class);

        // CAPTURANDO TODOS OS REGISTROS DO SHARED PREFERENCE

        Map<String, ?> allEntries = sharedPreferences.getAll();
              for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
                frasesFavoritoArray.add(entry.getKey().toString());

                frasesFavoritos = frasesFavoritoArray;

            }
```

Comment: O erro acontece no código que postou?

Comment: ramaral ela é passada para outra activity, reeditei a postagem agora. Desculpe.

Comment: Você já depurou para ver em que linha ele trava? mas para evitar o npe tu deveria verificar se é nulo antes de setar na view, pelo erro é só isso, tentando executar um método em um objeto nulo.